# Where does ActiveJdbc instrumentation compiler take information about database?

Tags: java, maven, activejdbc

If understood correctly, `ActiveJdbc` compiler should take as input hollow class like this

```
public class Employee extends Model {}
```

and fill it with some code from database metadata.

But how can it know where database is located?

I found only one place here http://javalite.io/getting_started where database is mentionned, namely

```
Base.open("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "user1", "xxxxx");
```

So, does instrumentation compiler scans code for calls to `Base.open()` and parses it for URL?

I can't believe it. What if there are multiple calls to different databases?

What if there is no `Base.open()` call?

Comment: Have you read http://javalite.io/instrumentation ? I don't think it connects to the database to do its job, which is mainly creating the static methods. It looks like it uses only what is described it the class code.

Comment: Nothing is described in class code. Classes are hollow in `ActiveJdbc`. Is is said in your link "Without instrumentation, ActiveJDBC would not be able to know what table to query." This means, that WITH instrumentation ActiveJDBC does know. My question is how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [activejdbc-instrumentation source](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/tree/master/activejdbc-instrumentation/src/main/java/org/javalite/instrumentation), what is does basically is:

- Find non-abstract subclasses of `org.javalite.activejdbc.Model` and for each class

  - Add methods that delegate to `org.javalite.activejdbc.Model`, which include:

    - `public static MetaModel getMetaModel()`
    - `public static List<String> attributes()`
    - `public static List<Association> associations()`
    - `public static int delete(String query, Object... params)`
    - `public static boolean exists(Object id)`
    - `public static int deleteAll()`
    - `public static int update(String updates, String conditions, Object ... params)`
    - `public static int updateAll(String updates, Object ... params)`
    - and more ...
  - Add `public static String getClassName()` method that returns the fully-qualified name of the class.
  - Add a line to the `activejdbc_models.properties` file containing `model.getName() + ":" + getDatabaseName(model) + "\n"`, where the first method returns the fully-qualified name of the class, and the second method returns the value of the `@DbName` annotation on the class or `"default"` if no annotation is found.

All database metadata is resolved in runtime, not during compilation or instrumentation phase.

Comment: This is a correct answer. ActiveJDBC, like ActiveRecord reads metadata from the database the first time you use any model class. Add `activejdbc.log` system property to see the output as it discovers tables  and relationships. For more on that, refer to: http://javalite.io/logging

Comment: @ipolevoy, can you please explain why this delegation is needed?

Comment: I assume you are asking why instrumentation is needed. If this is the case, see this page: http://javalite.io/instrumentation